# Open Explorer.exe and raise event when exe is exited

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have some code where I need the explorer exe application to open within code, which I have working now by using this:

```
Process explore = Process.Start(@"...explorer");
```

For some reason this doesn't work when I try to wait for the exe to be closed:

```
explore.WaitForExit();
```

Any reason why this doesn't work and how to fix it? a code snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here, but I think: Explorer runs as a single process (view it in task manager - it's 1 process regardless of how many windows you have open), so Process.Start isn't actually starting a new process in this case - it's opening a window in the existing `explorer` process.

Comment: @RB. How would I then have an event for that window?

Comment: "doesn't work when I try to wait for the exe to be closed" - please [edit] question to clarify what you expect to happen and what actually happens. "Doesn't work" rarely is enough of an explanation for the problem raised in a question.